# how to implement uninstall by drag to trash bin?

Tags: android, uninstallation

What do you have to do to enable uninstall of your app by long-press on icon and drag to trash bin at the top of the screen?

I've developed and installed an app on my phone, but can only uninstall by settings, application manager.

Comment: Does it work for other apps on your device?

Comment: Yes it works for other apps.

Comment: its device android (manufacturer) dependable you can not do anything about it

Comment: Do you mean the home screen or the app drawer?

Comment: This thing totally depends on the OS side unless you install some launcher in your phone.

Comment: Okk! Thank you so much for pointing that out. I searched for hours to find the right code to do that,  but I understand that it's based on the phone's OS now. Thanks again!